# Как вставить элемент после каждого элемента массива при помощи метода Insert()?

Tags: c#, arraylist, insert

Например:

```
    List<int> list= new List<int>(); // Создали пустой список

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) // Заполняем от 1 до 5 включительно
        list.Add(i);

    MessageBox.Show(string.Join("", list)); // Выводит: 12345

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Хотим вставить 0 после каждого елемента
        list.Insert(i + 1, 0);

    MessageBox.Show(string.Join("", list)); // Выводит: 1000002345
```

Как сделать так, что бы вывело `1020304050`?

Comment: Или с конца цикл сделать, или шаг 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = list.Count(); i > 0; i--)
{
    list.Insert(i, 0);
}
```